# How does a programming language support both functional and object oriented programming?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, programming-languages

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981969/156458

> There are two common approaches for a language to support both
>   functional and object oriented programming.
>
> - Every callable is a method and functions are just methods of a hidden class, which is the approach adopted by Ruby;
> - or every callable is a function and object methods are just functions with an implicit or explicit parameter that receives the
>     object the method was called from, which is the approach adopted by
>     Python.

Is it an accurate statement? What is the source of the statement?

What are the approaches for the following languages to support both functional and OO programming:

- Scala
- Java
- C#?

Thanks.

Comment: There are *other* approaches, but the *claim* was these are two common approaches... which is then substantiated with two examples. Scala, Java and C# are implemented with virtual machines (and the first two use the same virtual machine) - which means it's a combination of the programming language and runtime environment that enable it.

Comment: @NathanHughes do you mean scala uses a different approach than the two mentioned?

Comment: I think the quote is observing how language designers  tend to bolt on rudimentary support for FP as an afterthought. As a practical matter Scala would have to use the constructs, like classes, that are supported by the jvm. But nonOO jvm languages like clojure have to do that too

Comment: If you get what is a functional programming and OOP you will start to notice the aproaches the languages uses to support these features. I really recomend this video from Master Venka about funcional programming (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWKp-v0De9g)

Answer (score 3):

Functional Programming is based on concepts below:

- High order functions: You can pass functions to functions and return functions from functions. More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).
- Immutable objects: Objects that can't change the state after creation. More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).
- Pure functions: Functions with no side-effects, in another words, when a function receives an input, it will produce the same output everytime. More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

If you can do all this things, the language supports functional programming.

Scala:

- Is based on JVM, so supports OOP
- Has a [val](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/definition-details.html#val-and-var-definitions) syntax that creates an immutable object.
- Has support for [high order function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html)
- Programmer is responsible for creating pure functions

Java 8:

- Supports OOP
- Has the 'final' keyword and an effective final to make an object immutable
- Has support for high order functions with [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- Programmer is responsible for creating pure functions

C# supports functional programming too but I don't have the expertise to answer your question!