# Why does kotlin change method invocation by variable name

Tags: android, kotlin

If I write in Android Studio in a kotlin file getPackageManager this is automatically changed to "packageManager" in cursive, why does this happen and why should somebody think that this is straightforward to understand?

Comment: It is part of Kotlin -> Java interoperability: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: So, it means you could understand the cursive stuff like an alias? because normally what you write in a file is something that exists, if you write getPackageManager this exists somewhere, if you write the name of a variable this exists somewhere, but in this case packageManager doesn't really exist

Comment: "because normally what you write in a file is something that exists" -- [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2865865/115145).

Comment: Kotlin interprets Java bean-style getters and setters as *properties*. So while `packageManager` doesn't exist as a public *field*, Kotlin treats it as an actual *property*.

Answer (score 4):

> If I write in Android Studio in a kotlin file getPackageManager this is automatically changed to "packageManager" in cursive, why does this happen

`getPackageManager()` is a method written in Java. By convention, a method starting with `get` in Java is considered a *field accessor*. In Kotlin fields are accessed through *properties*. When inter-opting with Java, Kotlin automatically converts the Java way of accessing properties with the Kotlin way. This makes your code consistently "Kotliny" even if you're accessing Java classes.

> Why should somebody think that this is straightforward to understand?

Because - like the syntax in the Kotlin language itself - once you know how it works, it's straightforward to understand. This goes for most things one learns. Why would someone think this is *not* straightforward to understand?

> So, it means you could understand the cursive stuff like an alias? because normally what you write in a file is something that exists, if you write getPackageManager this exists somewhere, if you write the name of a variable this exists somewhere, but in this case packageManager doesn't really exist

Well, it does exist because the compiler makes it exist, otherwise it wouldn't compile, would it? It's just syntactic sugar. *You* see `packageManager` (so that - again - your code looks more like Kotlin). Meanwhile *the compiler* sees `getPackageManager()`. Either way it refers to the same thing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just a nit: it's the compiler which makes it exist, not the IDE, so it sees `packageManager`. Otherwise you couldn't compile the same code from the command line without the IDE.

Comment: "Why would someone think this is not straightforward to understand?" Because you must learn it, if you must learn it or you need an explanation to understand it it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the variables are private and their getter and setter are generated by the compilers, when you pick some value it is changed to getter or when you assign value it is changed to setter call by compiler.

```kotlin
class Obj(var variable = "Default Value")

val obj = Obj()
obj.variable            // same as obj.getVariable()
obj.variable = "Hello"  // same as obj.setVariable("Hello")
```

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters